# Switching to a different page without reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help figuring out how to load a different page into the current browser window. Basically, I made a home screen page and the actual game page.

Home page: http://jsfiddle.net/f7mL6wfu/2/

Game page: http://jsfiddle.net/brwsrr6s/

I want the button on the home page to change the current page to the game page. Is there a way to make this happen? So, in my home page, I need something like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Code to load a different page into the window theoretically goes here
});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Very nice game, by the way! I couldn't help notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy, use the JavaScript function `window.location`, as in the following code:

`window.location="http://www.example.com/";`

This code snippet uses the Locaion Object, which contains information about the current URL. It can be accessed through the `window.location` property.

Click the checkmark next to this answer if it was informative or helped you in any manner.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, so I'm going to check mark your answer once I am allowed to in a few minutes. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to make a kind of "fade effect" when switching between the pages? Or any other effect so that there is a cleaner transition?

Comment: Thanks! @saadq And sure, you could call a jQuery animation function (for example), and then use it's callback to send the `window.location`, ie. when it's already finished fading out. Example: `$("body").animate({ opacity: 0, backgroundColor: '#000' }, function() {
  window.location = "http://www.example.com/"
})`